# Julia create multiple slightly modified versions of a function

Tags: function, macros, closures, julia, metaprogramming

I have a function that looks like

```
function eom!(du, u, p)
    @views a, b = u[:,1], u[:,2];
    @views da, db = du[:,1], du[:,2];

    y = # some stuff involving p and a;
    da .= f(a, b, y);
    db .= g(b, a);
end
```

I now want to create a second a function that is the exact same, except the last line reads

```
db .= g(b, y);
```

How can I do this most cleanly? Of course, I could just copy and paste and give the functions slightly different names, but this seems unideal, especially if, as is plausible, I later want more functions where the second argument of `g` could be something else. Is there perhaps a way that I could pass into the function `eom!` an expression (via the argument `p`) that would specify the second argument of `g`? Or is there a way I could make some function `eom_generator` which can output all of the functions that I want? Perhaps macros are the central tool in doing this, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could produce a closure:

```
function eom_generator(g)
    return function eom!(du, u, p)
        @views a, b = u[:,1], u[:,2]
        @views da, db = du[:,1], du[:,2]

        y = nothing # some stuff involving p and a;
        da .= f(a, b, y)
        db .= g(a, b, y)
    end
end

const eom1! = eom_generator((a, b, y) -> g(b, a))
const eom2! = eom_generator((a, b, y) -> g(b, y))
```

But since this is at the core of a differential equation, be sure to test whether you don't have any performance issues that way.

If you decide that you really need metaprogramming, you can use `@eval` in a loop:

```
for (i, expr) in enumerate((:(g(b, a)), :(g(b, y))))
    @eval function $(Symbol("eom", i, "!"))(du, u, p)
            @views a, b = u[:,1], u[:,2]
            @views da, db = du[:,1], du[:,2]

            y = nothing # some stuff involving p and a;
            da .= f(a, b, y)
            db .= $expr
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It looks like the performance might suffer... `@time` indicates ~ 5 seconds vs ~ 50 seconds, though `@btime` indicates negligible difference. Surely there must be a better way though, something that effectively just prints two functions?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "better". Are you sure the benchmark excludes cimpilation times etc? But I'write an `@eval` solution later today.

Comment: @Grayscale There you are. Another thing you could try: replace the argument you give to `eom_generator` with an actual function; i.e., something like `g1(a::A, b::B, y::Y) = g(b, a); eom1! = eom_generator(g1)`. Maybe that helps. And have a look at the output of `@code_warntype`, of course.